# Error: GeoPoint long and lat is nil not allowing me to send coordinates due to Unwrapping Optional Value

Tags: firebase, swiftui, geolocation, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Hello I am stuck and have tried to google and research but am not having any luck. The user location is saying its nil. I am trying to send it to Firebase database to show the users location. When I print out the userLocation.coordinate.latitude manually it shows me the correct coordinates in the console. I have tried to put:

```
"location": GeoPoint(latitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)
```

To possibly unwrap the userlocation but no luck.

I am getting an ERROR:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
> Optional value

Current CODE:

```
// Sending to firebase database the order but location: is giving the optional value fatal error, while everything else is sending correctly
db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setData([

    "ordered_weed": details,
    "total_cost": calculateTotalPrice(),
    "location": GeoPoint(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

]) { (err) in

    if err != nil {
        self.ordered = false
        return
    }
    print("Success Order")
}
```

EDIT:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {      
    // reading user location and extracting details...
    self.userLocation = locations.last!
    self.extractLocation()
    // after extracting location logging in...
    self.login()
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to construct a json object. AFAIK, GeoPoint is not `Codable`.
So you may want to directly use the lat,lon from your userLocation.coordinate. Something like this: 

`if let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude, let lon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude {
 // "location": {"latitude": lat, "longitude": lon}  
}`

Comment: Where does a guy named 'GeoPoint' come from?  Firebase?  Which service are you referring to?  How are you getting data from it?

Comment: Yes GeoPoint comes from Firebase 'Firestore'.

Comment: I just need help on why my userLocation.coordinate.latitude and longitude is giving the GeoPoint a nil value. But when 'userLocation.coordinate.latitude' is printed it gives a coordinate.

Comment: GeoPoint just needs 2 double's lon and lat passed through. Which is what I am calling for.

Comment: I have figured out it works if i just put 0.0 and 0.0 for longtitude: and latitude: it sends it to the firebase store database. so it is something to do with userLocation.coordinate.latitude being an optional value.

Comment: if your problem is due to `userLocation`, show us the code you use to create and update `userLocation`. Where exactly do you print it? Show us the code so we can track down your problem. Have you tried using the `if let userLocation ...` like I showed you?

Comment: I edited my post with where I am updating userLocation. I have tried the if let userLocation but was getting an error due to it being inside the json object.. Also edited my current code above so you can see what im trying to fully send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out with the help of you `@workingdog` . The if let gave me the error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')

So I did some digging on swiftui forums and found this solution for forcing an unwrap. https://forums.swift.org/t/forced-unwrapping/38829/4

```
db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setData([

    "ordered_weed": details,
    "total_cost": calculateTotalPrice(),
    "location": GeoPoint(latitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
            
]) { (err) in
            
    if err != nil {
        self.ordered = false
        return
    }
    print("Success Order")
}
```

Comment: glad I could help, but your "solution" is doomed to fail you if you keep 
using force unwrapping in your code. Do not use it, avoid it like the plage.
Use `if let` with your `self.locationManager.location`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
if let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude, let lon = userLocation.coordinate.longitude {
    db.collection("Users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setData([
        "ordered_weed": details,
        "total_cost": calculateTotalPrice(),
        "location": {"latitude": lat, "longitude": lon}
    ]) { (err) in
        
        if err != nil {
            self.ordered = false
            return
        }
        print("Success Order")
    }
}
```

Don't put the `if let lat = ....` inside the json object.

Comment: I receive this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')